# Include single quote string in redshift dynamic SQL

Tags: dynamic-sql, redshift

I have function named

```
Schema.func_date(date,varchar)
```

I wanna do like this(I am using below statement inside Store proc)

```
Execute 'Select *, ID as Main_Id, ' ||
         'schema.func_date(quote_literal('2020-02-20'),quote_literal('ST')), '||
         'from main_table'
```

I am getting Invalid operation error while passing single quote string. How to pass the single quote string perfectly in execute statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the [`QUOTE_LITERAL()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_QUOTE_LITERAL.html) function is helpful in specific contexts, I think you still need to manually escape the single quotes when you use Dynamic SQL.

So your query should follow this:

```
Execute 'Select *, ID as Main_Id, ' ||
         'schema.func_date(quote_literal(''2020-02-20''),quote_literal(''ST'')), '||
         'from main_table'
```